# Serving Redmine on a Sub-URI using NGinX and uwsgi

Tags: nginx, redmine, uwsgi

I got Redmine working in `/`using NGinX and UWSGI but I'd like to serve it under `/redmine`. Below is the configuration:

```
location /redmine {
    gzip off;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/redmine.socket;
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_modifier1 7;
}
```

The uwsgi configuration is:

```
[uwsgi]
plugin = rack
master = true
processes = 4
socket = /tmp/redmine.socket
chmod-socket = 664
chdir = /opt/redmine
rack = ./config.ru
env = RAILS_ENV=production
```

I've already tried to include these lines:

```
mount = /redmine=config.ru
manage-script-name = true
```

as suggested in http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Nginx.html#dynamic-apps, but it didn't work. Then, I tried some suggestions listed in http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_in_a_sub-URI but none of them worked either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If uWSGI is working with Redmine, but just not accessible correctly via Nginx, then setting your `SCRIPT_NAME` and the uWSGI modifier1 to `30` like so:

```
location /redmine {
    gzip off;
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /redmine;
    uwsgi_modifier1 30;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/redmine.socket;
}
```

should solve your problem without the other configuration (see [uWSGI packet descriptions](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Protocol.html#packet-descriptions) for modifier values.

Under a slightly older version of Redmine, I had to resort to adding the following into the `config/additional_environment.rb` file:

```
begin
    ActionController::Base.relative_url_root = '/redmine'
rescue
    #nothing
end
```

and then also having Nginx rewrite access to the application like so:

```
location /redmine {
    [...]
    rewrite ^/redmine(.*)$ $1 break; 
    [...]
}
```

For note, this worked with Nginx doing a `proxy_pass` to the Rails app, rather than uWSGI, so may provide a fallback option.